# running node js app on another computer

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, socket.io

hi guys i'm new to javascript and node js and pardon my grammar :), so here is my prob i have a server.js running fine on computer but when i need another computer to access my server i think i need to insert a http request. How to insert the HTTP request on my server.js?? and i try to run on port 4000. Here is a sample of my code:

```
var connectedClients = {}; //used to keep a working list of the connections


var io = require('socket.io')(4000);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    //added clients
    socket.on("setClientId", function (data) {
        connectedClients[data.id] = { 
            id : data.id, //adds key to a map
            senderName : data.senderName
        }
        console.log(connectedClients);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Both computers need to be on the same network.

First get the local IP of of the development server.

Using a mac with bash shell you can run this command:

```
ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -v 127.0.0.1
```

The inet is the local ip.

Next make sure port 4000 is open on the firewall

Here's how to do this:

Mac->Sys Preferences->Sharing->Enable “Web Sharing” checkbox
Mac->Sys Preferences->Security-> Turn off firewall, or allow your application to accept incoming connection

Now on the other computer you should be able to access the node site via the inet ip + the port

will look something like this:

```
http://192.168.0.3:4000
```